# Python, Django. Extending user model with dictionary attribute

Tags: python, django

i have a problem.
This is how im trying to extend default User model:

```
# myapp models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    games = None

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Now i want to change 'games' attr when loggin in:

```
# myapp views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                # default value for games is None
                user.userprofile.games = {}
                # now it should be an empty dict
                login(self.request, user)
                return redirect('/game')

class Index(FormView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = request.user.get_profile()
        print profile.games # Prints 'None'
```

Well, my questions are:
Why 'print profile.games' prints 'None' and How can i change games attr when loggin in?

Comment: You forgot to do `save`? My wild guess.  Furthermore, by defaults `games` is None and `{}` is None because it's an empty dict.

Comment: @user1012451 Seems `save` didn't help. Btw, `d = {}; print d` will show `{}` instead of `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is a way to create field in the model.  You need to do it as:

```
game = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

And reset it to `None` or dict you want to store each time you login and save it.

In your login view:

```
import json
class LoginView(FormView):
    ....
    #your code
    if user.is_active:
        # default value for games is None
        user.userprofile.games = json.dumps({}) # some dict you want to store
        user.userprofile.save()   #save it

        # now it should be an empty dict
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('/game')
    ....
    #your other code
```

Problem with your code is that, value of `game` is not stored in DB. It is just an attribute of and instance. So it will not be preserved over different instances and every time you get an instance it will be reset to 'None`. In`Index`view you are getting new instance of`userprofile`which has 'game` set to `None`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, got it. I'll refactor it to the model of the game.